# TableView help pushing a custom view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

So I am trying to simple traverse to the next level of a table view by doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        FiltersController *aFiltersCont = [[FiltersController alloc] init];
        aFiltersCont.displayedFilters = [appDelegate.groupedBusiness allKeys];
        aFiltersCont.currentLevel = self.currentLevel + 1;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];
    }
}
```

is there any reason why this would not be pushing the controller?  I had a similar problem before, but solved it by displaying the view modally.  However, this time, this is in a popover and needs to slide to the next screen inside that popover.  Any Ideas?  Thanks in advance.

OK I am going to put some more source up here to try and help...

Inside the main view controller I have this code to make the popover from a button:

```
   // Create and configure the filters controller.
FiltersController *aFiltersController = [[FiltersController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
 self.filtersController = aFiltersController;
filtersController.appDelegate = self.appDelegate;



UINavigationController *filtersNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:filtersController];


UIPopoverController *filtersPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]     initWithContentViewController:filtersNavController];
self.filtersPopoverController = filtersPopover;
filtersPopoverController.delegate = self;
```

and then I have the code I first posted in my filtersController class.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Do us a favor and in the view you're trying to push add a NSLog statement in the ViewDidAppear method and see if its getting there. Also do a NSLog for indexPath.row and lets see what that is. Just throwing it out there in case cause the first row in your table is not at indexpath.row = 1 but at indexpath.row = 0

Comment: Ok the indexpath is fine.  That is not the issue.  I am stepping through the file, and as for the viewDidAppear, do you mean view will appear?  Because it does get to there, but I do not have a view did appear method...

Comment: Ok I have made somewhat of a breakthrough.  I got it to push the new view.  Apparently the problem lay in the fact that my filtersController class did not know about the navigation controller in the mainView class.  Now I just need to get it display the proper information.  I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just displaying your sublcass of `UITableViewController` inside a `UIPopoverController`, the `UINavigationController` will not be created for you automatically.  You may need to modify the code where you are creating the `UIPopoverController` with something like this:

```
MyTableViewController *table = [[[MYTableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:table] autorelease];
myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
```

Then you should be able to push and pop navigation controllers on the stack no problem.

Comment: Well I am creating a navigation controller, which is why this is so confusing.  Following all the logic I have seen, what I have should work.  I am really at a loss...

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];
```

Should be

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aFiltersCont animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yeah,  I actually caught that right after I posted this.  It was not the problem, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @gabaum10: Check that `self.navigationController` is not nil, and that `aFiltersCont` isn't nil.

Answer (score 0):

you are pushing `self` which is a reference to the current view controller. you should change the line with the push to the following if `aFiltersCont` is the viewController you are trying to drill to.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aFiltersCont animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused about the index. The first index is 0 not 1, so maybe you want `indexPath.row == 0`?

Also, you should release `aFiltersCont` before returning (you're leaking a `FiltersController` and anything it owns every time you run this method.

So maybe this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        FiltersController *aFiltersCont = [[[FiltersController alloc] init] autorelease];
        aFiltersCont.displayedFilters = [appDelegate.groupedBusiness allKeys];
        aFiltersCont.currentLevel = self.currentLevel + 1;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aFiltersCont animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the row doesn't really matter at this point.  That is something that will make a bigger difference once the view is pushing.  That is exactly what I have right now.